# Concatenate all the notes in a single row based on lead's ID?

Tags: mysql, sql, sugarcrm

I've a query to find all the notes for a lead in sugarcrm. As per the screenshot a lead have  3 or 4 notes.

I would like to concatenate all the notes in a single row (name column) based on lead's ID.

My query is,

---

```
SELECT l.first_name, l.last_name, l.id, n.name, n.description
FROM 
    leads AS l inner join notes as n on l.id = n.parent_id
where l.deleted = 0
and n.deleted = 0
and l.id='104c4b25-adab-32f3-16ee-50d098a5dd5d'
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [group_concat()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php) function

```
SELECT l.first_name, l.last_name, l.id, group_concat(n.name), n.description
FROM 
    leads AS l inner join notes as n on l.id = n.parent_id
where l.deleted = 0
and n.deleted = 0
and l.id='104c4b25-adab-32f3-16ee-50d098a5dd5d'
group by l.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) .

In your case, use the following syntax for a comma separated list :

```
SELECT l.first_name, l.last_name, l.id, n.name, n.description,
GROUP_CONCAT(n.name SEPARATOR ",") AS notes
FROM 
leads AS l inner join notes as n on l.id = n.parent_id
where l.deleted = 0
and n.deleted = 0
and l.id='104c4b25-adab-32f3-16ee-50d098a5dd5d'
GROUP BY l.id
```

This is typed out of my head, it may need refinings.